# How to create event, that triggered when user click on element (exception is 2 child element)

Tags: jquery

How to create event, that triggered when user click on element (exception is 2 child element). 
Html:

```
<div class="cc-window cc-banner cc-type-info cc-theme-block" style="">
    <span id="cookieconsent:desc" class="cc-message">This website uses cookies to improve your experience. To learn more, read our Privacy Policy. <a class="cc-link">Learn more</a></span>
    <div class="cc-compliance">
        <a class="cc-btn cc-dismiss">I ACCEPT</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

I tried

```
jQuery('.cc-window.cc-banner').not(jQuery(".cc-link").not(jQuery(".cc-btn.cc-dismiss"))).on("click", function () {
        alert("HI!");
    });
```

But alert was triggering if I tap `cc-btn`

Comment: You should pass through the event object and check that for target. Pseudo would look something like "click event(event) { if(event.target.hasClass(cc-btn) return; do the rest }

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have attached the event listener to the `cc-banner` div so it will always register the click even when you click a child element.

Try checking the event target inside the click handler. If the target class matches the elements you do not want to click, then return:

```
$('.cc-banner').on("click", function (e) {
  var $target = $(e.target);
  if($target.hasClass('cc-link') || $target.hasClass('cc-dismiss')) return;
  alert("HI!");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have your click event bound to everything, you need to check the target to handle the cases.

jsfiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/668326/

```
$('.cc-window.cc-banner').on("click", function (e) {
    var t = $(e.target);
    if(!t.hasClass("cc-btn")){
        alert("I did not click on '.cc-btn'")
    } else {
        return;
    }
```

});